# Execution failed for tahs in Android studio

Tags: android

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.

> Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1) differ. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details.

Comment: ¿y que estas realizando, cual es el código? revisa [ask].

Comment: no estaba realizando nada, esto es un mensaje de error que me sale nada mas abrir el android